# exception handling with NameError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception

I want to append new input to list SESSION_U without erasing its content. I try this:

```
... 
        try:
            SESSION_U.append(UNIQUES)
        except NameError:
            SESSION_U = []
            SESSION_U.append(UNIQUES)
...
```

I would think that at first try I would get the `NameError` and `SESSION_U` list would be created and appended; the second time `try` would work. But it does not. Do you know why? If this is not clear let me know and I will post the script. Thanks.

**Edit**

```
    # save string s submitted from form to list K:
    K = []        
    s = self.request.get('sentence')
    K.append(s)                              
    # clean up K and create 2 new lists with unique items only and find their frequency
    K = K[0].split('\r\n')     
    UNIQUES = f2(K)
    COUNTS = lcount(K, UNIQUES)
    # append UNIQUES and COUNTS TO session lists. 
    # Session lists should not be initialized with each new submission
    SESSION_U.append(UNIQUES)
    SESSION_C.append(COUNTS)
```

If I put `SESSION_U` and `SESSION_C` after `K = []` their content is erased with each submission; if not; I get `NameError`. I am looking for help about the standard way to handle this situation. Thank you. (I am working Google App Engine)

Comment: Definitely post more code.  This is a strange thing to try to do, BTW.   Why not just initialize your variable to []?

Comment: Just don't write code that raises a `NameError` because it doesn't not define a variable in a certain code path. Like, initialize it to a default value (here, `[]`). The snippet you posted works by the way, and unless there's some serious threading going on, I don't think it *can't* work...

Comment: @ Ned Batchelder: If I do SESSION_U = [] then each time the user submits a new text from the form the SESSİON_U is emptied. I want to save the session strings in SESSİON_U; so I want to append the string to it without erasing its content. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder, @delnan: I added more code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the code you posted is probably contained within a request handler.  What are your requirements regarding this `SESSION_U` list?  Clearly you want it to be preserved across requests, but there are several ways to do this and the best choice depends on your requirements.

I suspect you want to store `SESSION_U` in the [datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html).  You will need to use a [transaction](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html) to atomically update the list (since multiple requests may try to simultaneously update it).  Storing `SESSION_U` in the datastore makes it durable (i.e., it will persist across requests).

Alternatively, you could use [memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview.html) if you aren't worried about losing the list periodically.  You could even store the list in a global variable (due to [app caching](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#App_Caching), it will be maintained between requests to *a particular instance* and will be lost when the instance terminates).